# What would be a general meaning of logarithm in real world? In physics? In geometry?

Tags: logarithms

For example, we all know how enormous and wide spread the application of derivatives can be. Speed-acceleration, curve-tangent and so on. Any dynamic system has their particular examples.

Is there a similar examples for logarithm? What comes to your mind?

I can only think about tree-related situations. Like, building a tree with **n** leafs, it will consist of **log(n)** levels. And other cases, with diviving and branching.

I would appreciate to see any ideas :)

Comment: Try looking at Wikipedia for a start.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy sure I did, nothing general there

Comment: Look a little harder: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Applications

Comment: Slide rules !!!

Comment: How many bytes are needed to store an arbitrary integer between 0 or 1000000? Take logarithm with base 2.

Answer (score 3):

The logarithm is the inverse of the exponential function, so any practical problem that require exponential , also require logarithm.
There a lot of such problems. As starting examples You can search for:

radioactive decay ( in physics)

Interest rate ( in economy)

Population grow ( in biology)

And note also that logarithms was the instrument of calculus before computers.  E.g. : almost all the astronomical knowledges about the orbits of planets of the 1700-1800 and beginning 1900, comes from calculations made by means of logarithms.

Comment: Those are good examples to think about, thank you

Comment: And more: the sensibility of our senses is logarithmic. The scale of sound intensity ( decibel) is logarithmic. The scale of stars brightness (magnitude) is logarithmic.